# Design Time T4 Templates Using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Tags: .net, oracle, t4, oracle-manageddataaccess

I've been trying to convert some projects from using Oracle.DataAccess to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess. I've come across an issue that I can't figure out how to resolve.

I've attempted to run on all of these platforms with the same results:

- Visual Studio 2012, 2015, and 2017
- Windows 7 and 10
- .NET Framework 4, 4.5, 4.7.1

I've gotten a project to work with the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess project by adding the required sections to the app.config file. I've successfully got that working using LDAP, TNS_ADMIN, and the TNS data source directly in the app.config.

However, when I try and apply that to a project using T4 Text Templates, I get the dreaded error: tns:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

So my question is, has anyone come across this issue and if so, how did you resolve? Or does anyone have any debug suggestions of how I can find out where exactly this is failing?

Also note that I've added a Pre-Build Event script to grab the required NuGet packages as I believe the text templates are executed pre-compile.